# Upload data to backend and image to external server

Tags: android, ios, file-upload

I have two mobile apps (iOS & Android) and a Java backend. Lets say the apps allow the user to add new content, and each content has some basic info (String or Int fields) and some media associated. Due to performance, we have decided that the images should be stored in [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com), while the rest of the information is stored in the backend server with Postgres.

As you may imagine, the data must be stored consistently so that users can fetch the information uploaded by others later. Therefore, the Content model would look something like:

```
class Content {
   Int id;
   String name;
   String description;
   String imageUrl;
}
```

The imageUrl string corresponds to the URL path where the image can be fetched. I do know how to upload and download the image from Cloudinary, but I still don't know how should the sequence of the actions be. My options are:

Option A: Upload the image. Obtain the URL where it is hosted, set it to the Content instance and then send the content to the backend. Notify user everything was done OK.

Option B: Upload the content to the backend without setting the path to the image. Notify user content was sent OK. Upload the image in background thread, and if it is uploaded correctly, update the imageUrl in the backend to the corresponding path.

Option C: Upload the content to the backend setting the path I know the image will have. Notify user content was sent OK. Upload the image in background thread, and if there is any problem in the upload, update the imageUrl in the backend to null.

What do you think is the best option?

Answer (score 0):

I would choose A option, because user can stop activity before you background uploading will complete.